# Grab class from each element and move to next element in line - like a round robin

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a circle with icons placed around it using CSS. On mouseenter or click, the html content is stored as a variable belonging to the icon and output inside the center of the circle. Each icon has a class that determines its position. (e.g. first, second, third, etc).

I would like to move whichever icon is active to the top (first) and position all the other in line respectively. So, if I click/mouseenter on the icon with a class of "third", I would like to: 
a) remove the 'active' class from the active element (done)
b) add the 'active' class to this element (done)
c) change this element's class to 'first', which would make the fourth element's class be 'second', the fifth's 'third' and so on down the line.

I started by doing 'each' to store the current class in a variable, but I and then going to the parent() to change the class attr(), but couldn't figure out how to target this in a round robin style to move the class down the line. You can see below the code to move the 'active' class as well as the html content. I also have a codepen mocked up here: https://codepen.io/jphogan/pen/KqdNYZ

```
// on circle click add/remove class and replace html 
$('.icon_circle_container .icon_circle').on('mouseenter click', function() {
    // if it's already active, do nothing, but return false
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        // otherwise...
        $('.icon_circle_container .icon_circle.active').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from element that has it
        $(this).addClass('active'); // add active class to this element
        newData = $(this).find('.icon_circle_content').html(); //store html as attribute
        $('.icon_circle_container .center .icon_circle_content').fadeOut(function() { // fade out old content
            $(this).html(newData).fadeIn(); // fade in new html content
        }); // replace with stored data
        return false;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/jondcampbell/pen/jwWMQN?editors=1011)

```
(function($) {



$(document).ready(function() {
    // on circle click add/remove class and replace html
    $(".icon_circle_container .icon_circle").on("click", function() {
      // if it's already active, do nothing, but return false
      if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        return false;
      } else {
        // otherwise...

    // What is the new active index
    var new_item = $(this).attr('data-item-index');

    // How many items total
    var items_count = $('.icon_circle').length;

    // Rotate
    $('.icon_circle').each(function( index ) {
      var adjusted_index = index + 1; // Since js indexes from 0
      var difference = adjusted_index - new_item;
      if(difference == 0){
        console.log('activate '+ adjusted_index);         
      }else{
        console.log('not active '+adjusted_index);
        if(difference > items_count){
          difference = difference - items_count;
        }else if(difference < 1){
          difference = difference + items_count;
        }         
      }
      var position = difference + 1;    
      // This is where you can active things and set the proper position class on the item
      $(this).removeClass('position-1 position-2 position-3 position-4 position-5').addClass('position-' + position);
    });

    $(".icon_circle_container .icon_circle.active").removeClass("active"); // remove active class from element that has it
    $(this).addClass("active"); // add active class to this element
    newData = $(this).find(".icon_circle_content").html(); //store html as attribute
    $(
      ".icon_circle_container .center .icon_circle_content"
    ).fadeOut(function() {
      // fade out old content
      $(this).html(newData).fadeIn(); // fade in new html content
    }); // replace with stored data
    return false;
  }
});
// end document ready
  });
  // end jquery wrap
})(jQuery);
```

Key things:

I changed the classes for the positions to be numeric (position-1, position-2, etc).

I didn't look at your animation or fading stuff.

Essentially the stuff from line 38 down(your old stuff) may still need to apply differently around line 35 where I set the position class.

It loops through each item and figures out what position class to assign to that particular element based on where they clicked and the original data-item-index number.
We are going to assume that the order of the elements in the dom schematically is the same as the data-item-index.
In theory, we could probably drop the data-item-index and use some jquery to figure out where the clicked item fits into that order of the 5 icons in its parent but I didn't bother.